# Random native crash in Webrtc peerconnection while disconnecting

Tags: android, android-ndk, webrtc

I am using webrtc for making video calls. My use case is such that I connect to users in queue one after another. So connect to user1, end connection with user1 then connect to user2 and so on.

At times while disconnecting from user and disposing off the peerconnection I come across this native crash

```
E/rtc(6882): #\
05-26 17:30:44.374: E/rtc(6882): # Fatal error in ../../webrtc/sdk/android/src/jni/peerconnection_jni.cc, line 1074\
05-26 17:30:44.374: E/rtc(6882): # last system error: 17\
05-26 17:30:44.374: E/rtc(6882): # Check failed: 0 == (reinterpret_cast<PeerConnectionInterface*>(j_p))->Release() (0 vs. 1)\
05-26 17:30:44.374: E/rtc(6882): # Unexpected refcount.\
05-26 17:30:44.374: E/rtc(6882): #\
```

This crash happens very randomly and from what I can guess is that something is keeping a reference to peerconnection while disposing.

Here is my code for disposing of peer connection, I am reusing local media stream for new connections.

```
videoCapturer.stopCapture();
if (peerConnection != null) {
        peerConnection.close();
        peerConnection.removeStream(localMediaStream);
        peerConnection.dispose();
        peerConnection = null;
}
```

is the above snippet correct way to dispose of peer connection? What could be the reason for randomness for this crash? Is the leaked reference inside Java layer or native layer?

Answer (score 4):

These crashes are expected if you are creating multiple peerConnections from same factory and disposing them.

**Workaround:** Stop disposing peerConnection, as `peerConnection.dispose();` will destroy local streams and etc.
Just use `peerConnection.close();` and use `peerConnection.dispose();` only for final `peerConnection` object.

Star the bugs [7543](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/webrtc/issues/detail?id=7543) and [7691](https://bugs.chromium.org/p/webrtc/issues/detail?id=7691) for the updates on this

Comment: hmm I am indeed creating multiple peer connections from same factory, but isn't it supposed to be done that way only? Will check how memory usage is affected if I don't dispose `peerConnection` as I expect creation of lots of peerConnections( more than 20 at times).

Comment: No it won't leak any memory if you dispose at the end. See https://chromium.googlesource.com/external/webrtc/+/master/webrtc/sdk/android/api/org/webrtc/PeerConnection.java#305

Answer (score 0):

For those troubleshooting similar issues, I was implementing a multiple peerConnection approach in Android where peers would be closed when disconnecting.

It seems that when you call `peerConnection.close()` from a synchronous thread, the native call never seems to complete. So if you try to create a new peer connection `peerConnectionFactory.createPeerConnection(...);`, it will hang on the `nativeCreatePeerConnection` call. Based upon other posts, it seems that the original close call is waiting for other resources to close, but just hangs given it was on a main thread.

**The solution**
Simply call the `peerConnection.close()` call from an asynchronous executor thread or something similar.

```java
ExecutorService executor = Executors.newSingleThreadExecutor();
executor .execute(() -> {
     this.pc.close();
});
```

This seems to allow the native connection to close properly and will allow you to continue to create peerConnections from that same factory